# Is the web browser performance rule "only 2 requests in parallel per hostname" still correct?

Tags: performance, http, browser, frontend

In his book "High Performance Websites" Steve Souders wrote (2007) that browsers limit parallel requests to a domain/hostname to two at a time. Is this still valid today?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost incorrect today.

Most browsers have upgraded to 6 parallel connections. See Steve Souder's [Browserscope > Network tab > Connections per Hostname](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=top). Older browsers still restrict to 2 connections - that may or may not be relevant to you depending on the browsers your application supports.

Comment: Ah actual tests of real browsers. Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Firefox bumped up its maximum per-server connection count from 8 to 15 for Firefox 3 and later. The maximum is less for servers that support persistent connections:

- Firefox 2: 2
- Firefox 3: 6
- Opera 9.26: 4
- Safari 3.0.4: 4
- IE 7: 2
- IE 8: 6 (except on dial-up)

Answer (score 2):

2 years later the same Steve Souders wrote in "Even Faster Web Sites":

> IE8 and FF3 both increase the number of connections per server from two to six.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP/1.1 spec suggests a cap of 2 simultaneous requests per host (With HTTP/1.0 a figure of 4 was more common).

It would be wise to assume that the client might not be able to have more than 2 simultaneous requests open at once.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 is over 12 years old. The next revision is making changes to this. See http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/131

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there may be some variations, but that limitation is certainly still valid. Some browsers might allow more than two parallel requests to a host, but it's still only a few.

There may also be limitations on the server side. If you are requesting active pages, e.g. ASP/ASP.NET/PHP, they are usually limited to a single request at a time per user.

However, with bandwith increasing this limitation has a smaller impact than it had in 2007. Eventhough you can still only do a few requests in parallel, each request is faster so the limitation is not very noticable.