# Minimising number of requests vs Browser Caching & Multiple domains

Tags: performance, frontend

I have recently been working on improving the front end performance of our website and have been employing a number of best practices.

However I have had a recent example where some of the practices are slightly at odds with each other

- Minimise HTTP requests
- In order to "trick" the browser into making more concurrent requests have some assets served from a different domain
- Leverage browser caching

Why?

We used to bundle almost all of our Javascript into one file to minimise HTTP requests. This included JQuery and JQuery UI.

I thought this was silly as many users are likely to have JQuery already cached in their browser so I decided we should remove it from our all.js and instead serve it from Google's CDN. This would save users downloading the code again and because it's on a different domain it can be downloaded in parallell with other resources from our own domains.

The concurrent downloading is shown in the graph below:

[image: Effect of using Google'CDN for concurrent downloads]

This of course has raised the number of requests for people without JQuery already cached which isn't great though.

So my question is this:

**Is the change a sensible one? Do the benefits of leveraging caching and allowing concurrent requests outweigh a slight increase in the number of requests?**

Answer (score 2):

That is a *very good question*.

You have explained your reasoning well and they are all good reasons for making this change.

But there still remains benefits to both approaches.

**Keeping everything combined in one file**

- Reduce number of HTTP requests, reduces the negative effects of round-trip latency on the user's connection.
- All libraries/plugins are downloaded at once, and should remain cached for when they are later needed.
- Reduce dependency on other services (although, Google is going to be quite reliable).

**Separate files spread across domains**

- Increase parallelisation of downloads, reduces the negative effects of bandwidth shaping on the user's connection.  (*Note that most browsers [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753898/is-the-web-browser-performance-rule-only-2-requests-in-parallel-per-hostname-s?rq=1) limit concurrent per-domain requests to 2 anymore though.*)
- Increase granularity - separate parts can be downloaded on-demand as needed, ie if a particular plugin is not needed on the first page hit, it isn't downloaded.

Personally, I'd normally lean a little bit towards the former (reducing HTTP requests by combining them into one big file).  I feel like most of my audience is going to be on a fairly high-bandwidth connection and I can reduce latency.  Remember to use Google and Yahoo's page speed tools to find other ways of speeding things up.

Comment: Thanks, I certainly am using these tools and we're doing pretty well, still some things to do. What are your thoughts on JQuery being quite likely to be cached anyway, due to it's relative ubiquity. Users who already have it cached will effectively download it twice if you go for the keeping everything in one file approach.

Comment: I'd generally still go for combining them into one file to reduce HTTP requests.  However, jQuery is big enough these days (>30KB gzipped) that on slower connections that transfer time begins to matter more than the overhead of an HTTP request, in which case if the user has Google's instance cached it's a win.  You can also trust Google to have the caching controls and gzip configured correctly.