# What are pros of external json file without dynamic data?

Tags: javascript, json

I am writing an JS a script that takes outside data. The data will never change during runtine. Are there any pros of puting it in external JSON file and not just in the .js or even .html file?

I can think of two cons: it's an extra request and it requires an extra event to fire after the external file was loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, we could technically stuff everything a site needs in a single HTML document:

- Stylesheets
- Scripts
- Data
- Pictures

Whether that's useful or not depends on the kind of app we are developing. For general purpose Internet-based web sites it's probably a bad idea:

- You need automated build scripts to inject all assets in place (unless you're willing to face a maintenance mess). Need for automation is not necessarily a con but it's a requisite you need to account for.
- The download is huge and you probably cannot benefit from partial rendering.
- It's impossible to leverage proxy or browser cache, unless the HTML itself is made static.
- It's not possible to release partial upgrades.

Whatever, your mileage may vary.

Comment: So, in my case of compiled middleman with data from .yml file, external file is useless. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how big the JSON file is.

If the JSON large and delays the loading of any subsequent CSS files, that would be undesirable. The sooner the CSS is loaded, the sooner your webpage "looks like" your webpage.

Also consider the number of requests going to the JSON file's hostname. You want to keep under the max parallel requests (previous 2, now 6 - see [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753898/is-the-web-browser-performance-rule-only-2-requests-in-parallel-per-hostname-s))

And finally, if I may stand on this soap box: it will be easier to manage if it is external. I would recommend increased manageability / adaptability to a small speed increase *most* of the time.